# Arrays in Drupal static queries

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, drupal-modules

I have query in which I would like to pass the result of a MS SQL statement to a variable. Not sure how to do this.

My query:

```
 if($view->id() == 'program_search'  && 
  !empty($searched_miles_value) &&
  !empty($searched_zip_value) &&
  ($searched_miles_value != 'any')) {

    $connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
    $result = $connection->query("SELECT to_zip FROM zipmaster_xref WHERE from_zip = '".$searched_zip_value."' AND miles = '".$searched_miles_value."'")-> fetchAll();

    $target_zips = $result ; //this line is not working
    foreach($result as $zip) {
      $target_zips[] = $zip->to_zip;
    }

    $query->addWhere('new_group', 'node__field_zip.field_zip_value', $target_zips, 'IN');
```

I want to pass the $result array into $target_zips and loop through it. Can any one help me to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: The `return $result->fetchAll` is returning the value somewhere and the code after that isn't executed.

Comment: yeah...any way this can be fixed? Originally I was not having that line. All I had was a simple fetch all at the end of previous query line. which also was not working!

Comment: It's better if you read the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Thanks. FetchAll doesn't create any issue. My problem is with the line after that. Not sure how to pass the $result to target_zips field.

Comment: Why would you set `$target_zips = $result ;` and then loop over $result setting $target_zips again?? Wouldn't you just set $target_zips to an empty array before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

before fetch your data you have to execute the query for example :

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT to_zip FROM zipmaster_xref WHERE from_zip = '".$searched_zip_value."' AND miles = '".$searched_miles_value."'")->execute()->fetchAll();
```

But this usage is not correct at all.Passing variable to the query directly causing SQL Injection be avoid from this  you should use placeholders read the documentations first please.
An example for placeholders :

```
$query = $database->query("SELECT id, example FROM {mytable} WHERE created > :created", [
  ':created' => REQUEST_TIME - 3600,
]);
```

Drupal 8 static query documentation can be found at : https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/database-api/static-queries